# TypeORM save() array of object ignore @PrimaryColumn() and create dublicates

Tags: typescript, typeorm

I Have entity Point:

```
@Entity()
export class Point {

        @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
        id: string;

        @IsUUID()
        @PrimaryColumn({
               type: 'uuid',
                unique: true,
                primary: true,
        })
        deliveryTerminalId: string;
}
```

Then I get structure like this from another API,

```
export interface DeliveryTerminalsInterface {
    deliveryTerminalId: string;
}
```

And I want to save array of DeliveryTerminalsInterface, like Point. (I do sync data, my own entity Point will have much more @Colums() in future)

```
await this.pointRepository.save(ArrayOfDeliveryTerminalsInterface);
```

It is save, create array of entity. But if I do sync method again, it don’t update exit entity by deliveryTerminalId primary key, it create new one. And in DB now two entity with same PrimaryColumn as deliveryTerminalId.

How this possible, what do wrong? Maybe I need use another way to save/update this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using two `Primary` column identifiers. You cant have both `@PrimaryGeneratedColumn` and `@PrimaryColumn` in the same entity. Remove one of them and try.

[Creating Primary Column](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm#creating-a-primary-column)

[Creating an auto generated column](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm#creating-an-auto-generated-column)

Try changing your code to the following:

```
@Entity()
export class Point {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id: string;

    @IsUUID()
    @Column({
       type: 'uuid',
       unique: true
    })
    deliveryTerminalId: string;
}
```

And if `id` is there in the saving object, then the said object will be updated.

```
await this.pointRepository.save(pointSaveObj);
```